# How to download oracle form attachments using concurrent program

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I'm having a requirement, which is to download the attachments in the in the form or FNDLOBS using the concurrent program (A zip or PDF file should get downloaded in the browser once the concurrent program completed)

Please suggest the if anyone has idea about this.

Thanks!!